# Detecting hair in a portrait image?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-manipulation

What would be the best approach for detecting and removing a person's hair in a simple portrait image ?  Any useful libraries of algorithms ?  I have been looking over openCV which looks like it could be of some use

Comment: did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: did you find a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 12):

You're dealing with two different problems here:

1. detecting if a face in a portrait has hair
2. "removing" the hair

The first is solvable fairly easily:

- Separate the face from the background (as you've mentioned a "simple portrait image", this shouldn't be too hard).
- Convert your image to the [Y'CbCr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) color space
- Human skin has a fairly narrow range of chrominance values, regardless of race.  Check out [this paper](http://www.ee.cuhk.edu.hk/~knngan/TCSVT_v9_n4_p551-564.pdf) for the details.
- The approach above will help you separate skin areas of the face from non-skin areas
- Assume that the non-skin areas consist of hair.  Note that facial hair will get picked up as a non-skin area, too.

As far as the second problem goes, you need to clarify exactly what you mean by "removing":

- Are you simply cutting out the part of the portrait that has hair?  In this case, the solution follows directly from the detection method above.
- Are you trying to make it look like the person has no hair at all (e.g. is bald, clean-shaven?)  In this case, things will be a lot harder -- there's a reason why professional photo manipulators get paid well.

Comment: Hi, when you say separate hair. Any idea how this can be performed using Open CV?

Answer (score 11):

I think this is hard problem - consider for detecting and removing hair in this case:
[image]

I found several papers, maybe they will help you:

- [Detection and analysis of hair](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~yaser/pamis.pdf)
- [Dullrazor®: A software approach to hair removal from images](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6T5N-3RXPN9C-6&_user=10&_coverDate=11%2F30%2F1997&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1623315354&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=1b5f70376dc6f3a945af8abf59f48100&searchtype=a)
- [Research on the Expression of Hair in Computer Animation](http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTOTAL-JSGG199912017.htm)

Cheers!

Answer (score -2):

try this http://betaface.com/demo.html . Color , hair info and more . smile , age, eye etc..

Comment: Is this made with opencv?