# Detecting Hair Open CV iPhone

Tags: iphone, face-detection

I just ran a sample code using opencv for face detection. It is detecting the edges and face quite nicely.

I was wondering, if anyone has any idea how I can somehow differentiate hair and face? I know we can probably use the hair colour contrast but someone else pointed out that if the person is blond, it won't work.

Any ideas or suggestions are more than welcomed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Thumbs up for unintended racism :P

Comment: Lol, if only everyone had the same skin & hair colour. That would have made life so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another thread in SO about detecting hair in a face picture with OpenCV: [Detecting hair in a portrait image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822999/detecting-hair-in-a-portrait-image) . It has some cool ideas and links to a paper which might be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that. Was looking at that post earlier. Any idea how I could use opencv to detect hair ?

Comment: Do you have access to the IEEE website? I was also curious, and found [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?reload=true&url=http://ieeexplore.ieee.org\/iel5/10347/32910/01541327.pdf%3Farnumber%3D1541327&authDecision=-203), but i'm not at the uni at the moment, so i can't check it out.

Comment: nope no access unfortunately.Detecting hair seems to be quite tricky.