# Hair detection using OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv

Is it possible to detect black hair using opencv in Android, i have tried couple of example that shows face detection. But now how can i detect hair ?

Thanks

Comment: the albino people must be annoyed with this question :P +1

Comment: Have you able to calculate hair count? Can you please share some code or reference to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as well

[Detecting hair in a portrait image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822999/detecting-hair-in-a-portrait-image)

http://aishack.in/tutorials/hough-transform-in-opencv/

Both are good one.

Comment: Can you please share some code or reference to count hair from image using OpenCV?

Comment: can you please share some code for detecting hair from image

Answer (score 3):

This is just an idea but you can try the following:

1- Detect the face

2- Expand ROI by a certain factor (play with it a bit)

3- Detect hair on a color based approach.

Comment: Can you please share some code or reference to count hair from image using OpenCV?

Comment: @HareshChhelana if you use images of bald men, the count will be 0. Works every single time.