# Classify the hair and face in android

Tags: android, face-detection, haar-classifier, android-paint

I want to Classify the hair and face in android so that I can apply some cosmetic effects on the face, without affecting the hair.

However, everyone has different hair style and some of their hair color are close to their face color. Nowadays, most of the libraries or web services only provide the detection for the face. How can I classify the hair and face color in android or is there any haar-classifier for me to do that ??

Please give me some advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this :

- Recognize the face with [opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier)
- Convert the image to the [Y'CbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) color space
- Seperate the face from the hair
- Detect the color of the hair

  You can also check this question [Detecting hair in a portrait image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822999/detecting-hair-in-a-portrait-image).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If the hair color are black and the skin color are yellow, I can detect them but when the hair color and the skin color are both yellow tone, then how can I tackle it?

Comment: I've been reading this [paper](http://www.ee.cuhk.edu.hk/~knngan/TCSVT_v9_n4_p551-564.pdf), where they explain in - depth how the human face has a
special color distribution that differs significantly (although
not entirely) from those of the background objects ( including hair). They create a skin-color map by adopting histograming technique on a given set of training data. Basically there is no easy way to detect the hair, if you are really interested you should give it a read.

Comment: I know that this would be a tough work and thank you for the paper that you provide. But most of the color difference between the hair and skin are not really close.

Comment: @ng2b30 could you manage to distinguish whether face has hair or not